# Filter an evaluated QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django

The requirement is for me to be able to access members of an *evaluated* QuerySet by a string attribute, in this case `name`. I don't like the idea of looping over a QuerySet as it seems like there is a more efficient way.

After I've called something like:

```
my_objects = MyObject.objects.all()
```

And I evaluate it with something like:

```
len(my_objects)
```

What is the best way to get a specific result by name from an evaluated QuerySet, in this case `my_objects`? Ideally I'd like to see something like `my_objects.filter(foo='bar')`.

Note I'll need all of the results in the evaluated QuerySet during the course of the process, so that's why I have it in one initial query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this to get a object based on field value from queryset. But you can do one thing is to create a dictionary from queryset and set `name` as key (must be unique):

```
my_objects = MyObject.objects.all()
obj_dict = {obj.name: obj for obj in my_objects}
print obj_dict['any_name']
```

FYI: If you want to just retrieve a single object from table then you can use [.get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) method:

```
obj = MyObject.objects.get(pk=id)
or
obj = MyObject.objects.get(name='unique_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluated queryset is a list. There is no indexation of list elements, so looping is required anyway. But evaluated queryset is assumed to be not so huge, max few hundreds of entries so looping is ok. Do not evaluate large querysets.

By the way, similar lists of objects are created by `prefetch_related()`. There is an implementation of `ListQuerySet` which supports many filters, ordering and distinct, making possible to run many (not all though) queries for such lists of objects:

https://github.com/Dmitri-Sintsov/django-jinja-knockout/blob/master/django_jinja_knockout/query.py

Comment: Evaluated queryset is still a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

[@aamir-rind's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14160699) is great, but it only works if `name` is unique.

If `name` is not unique, you could, for example, collect the objects in a list:

```py
# map name to list of objects
my_objects_dict = dict()
for obj in my_objects:
    key = obj.name
    if key not in my_objects_dict:
        my_objects_dict[key] = []
    my_objects_dict[key].append(obj)
```

If `my_objects` has not been evaluated yet, the loop will evaluate it. If `my_objects` has already been evaluated, e.g. as in `my_objects = list(MyModel.objects.all())`, it will not be evaluated again.